# Xamarin.Forms: how to center a multine label in a Row?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid, label

I try to vertically center a [multiline Label](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2016/06/27/xamarin-forms-multi-line-label-custom-renderer-gotcha/) that contains a text that can be displayed on 1 or 2 lines.

For the moment, I'm not able to get the expected rendering...

I can have the multiline label that automatically extends but it is top aligned and not centered:
[image: label is not centered]

This is the attached XAML:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<local:MultiLineLabel
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="Orange"
    Text="{ Binding encart_titre }"         
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
    Lines="2"
    ...
/>
```

I can also center the label, but in this case it doesn't auto extends:
[image]

This is the attached XAML:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<local:MultiLineLabel
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="Orange"
    Text="{ Binding encart_titre }"         
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
    Lines="2"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    ...
/>
```

***Would you have any explanation? I also tried to add StackLayound around the Label, but this didn't change anything...***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first choice for centering a control would be to use `VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"`, have you tried that instead of `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`? [Here's more information](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options/) about the LayoutOptions in Xamarin.Forms.

So, this would be the correct way to center vertically:

```
<local:MultiLineLabel
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="Orange"
    Text="{ Binding encart_titre }"         
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
    Lines="2"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" <!-- This one here -->
    ...
/>
```

Comment: thank you it works with `VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"`

Comment: Just a little specification: the label must be embedded in a `StackLayout` with `VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` and `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"`.